# Why i can't use appbartheme to define the title in AppBar class

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to set the appbarTheme for the Appbar but i can't.

Here is my appbarTheme

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Helo mu baby',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        //Some Widget will use accentColor first and use primarySwatch like insure
        accentColor: Colors.amber,
        textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
               titleLarge: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
        ),
        fontFamily: "QuickSand",
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                titleLarge: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.indigo,
                  fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                  fontSize: 45,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
        ),
      ),
      home: MyHomeApp(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my AppBar and i use "titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.titleTextStyle" to define the theme but it is not correct.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(  
      appBar: AppBar(
     titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.titleTextStyle,
        //100px
        title: Text("Helo mu baby"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: (() {
                _startAddNewTransaction(context);
              }),
              icon: Icon(Icons.add))
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don' use `textTheme` because it is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

> 'textTheme' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. This property is no longer used, please use toolbarTextStyle and titleTextStyle instead.

[image: titleTextStyle]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Helo mu baby',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        //Some Widget will use accentColor first and use primarySwatch like insure
        accentColor: Colors.amber,
        /*'accentColor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. 
         * Use colorScheme.secondary instead. For more information, 
         * consult the migration guide at 
         * https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties#migration-guide. 
         This feature was deprecated after v2.3.0-0.1.pre..*/
        textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
              titleLarge: const TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
        fontFamily: "QuickSand",
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          /*
          textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                titleLarge: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.indigo,
                  fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                  fontSize: 45,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              */
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.indigo,
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
            fontSize: 45,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: MyHomeApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.titleTextStyle,
        //100px
        title: const Text("Helo mu baby"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: (() {
                //_startAddNewTransaction(context);
              }),
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined a textTheme in your appbarTheme, and use a titleTextStyle in your appbarTheme, of course it won't do the work.
Try this.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Helo mu baby',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        //Some Widget will use accentColor first and use primarySwatch like insure
        accentColor: Colors.amber,
        textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
               titleLarge: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
        ),
        fontFamily: "QuickSand",
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          titleTextStyle: ThemeData.light().appBarTheme.titleTextStyle.copyWith(fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,)
        ),
      ),
      home: MyHomeApp(),
    );
  }
}
```